# How to set the value of the deepest nested properties of an object to a string of all its preceding keys?

Tags: javascript

In other words, how to turn `original` into `expected`, or how to  set the values of keys which values are empty strings with a dot notation formatted representation of the key's "path" inside the object ?

```
original = {
 A: {
   B: {
    C: {
      D: "",
      E: ""
    },
    F: {
      G: "",
      H: ""
    }
   }
 }
}

expected = {
  A: {
    B: {
      C: {
        D: "A.B.C.D",
        E: "A.B.C.E
      },
      F: {
        G: "A.B.F.G",
        H: "A.B.F.H"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Surely people must have stumbled on this kind of issue when dealing with "stringly-typed" systems ?

Comment: Know how to post a [mcve] that has actual JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done in that way:

```js
const original = {
 A: {
   B: {
    C: {
      D: "",
      E: ""
    },
    F: {
      G: "",
      H: ""
    }
   }
 }
}

const addPath = (data, path = []) => {
  return Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, key) => {
    const currentPath = [...path, key]
    return {
      ...acc,
      [key]: typeof data[key] === 'object'
        ? addPath(data[key], currentPath)
        : currentPath.join('.')
    }
  }, {})
}

console.log(addPath(original))
```